# When I have a THREE.js app open in Chrome my Browser drags bad

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am building a small 2D game with THREE.js and I just noticed while I have a tab open with my THREE.js app loaded up the rest of my tabs start dragging to a snail's pace. But when I switch tabs meaning the THREE.js tab is hidden everything goes back to normal. Is there any way around this? I believe it most likely has something to do with the requestAnimationFrame(render) function running recursively. Any tips on how to optimize THREE.js requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: Do you have multiple browser windows open? I've had a similar problem but only when I've run a THREE.js game in one window and lets say Linkedin in another. Good question..

Comment: @HannaMcquaig Yes, that is exactly what I'm talking about. With one window open it's not noticeable. Tanks

Comment: show us you render function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Three.js setups re-render the scene 60 times per second, which is no easy task for lots of machines. Running a WebGL website is always going to be more resource-intensive than a standard HTML page. Optimizing each frame is entirely dependent on what you're using, so there's no absolute answer to how to optimize it. It's almost always a balance between performance and visual quality. Here are some common culprits that might be causing performance issues, although this list is far from being exhaustive:

- High Mesh count (try merging geometries and [instancing](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=instan#webgl_instancing_dynamic) when meshes repeat)
- Too many lights (try baking [light-maps](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=lightmap#webgl_materials_lightmap) to use as few dynamic lights as possible)
- Rendering at high DPI (try to [set a pixel ratio of 1](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setPixelRatio) if possible)
- Anti-aliasing (no AA is cheaper than using AA)
- Complex shadows (try baking shadows instead of using dynamic shadows whenever possible)
- Complex shaders (some photo-realistic shaders can be expensive to compute)
- Expensive post-processing
- Full-screen rendering (rendering at 1920x1080 is way more expensive than 1024x768)
- Discrete GPU (having a separate graphics card gives substantially better performance than shared graphics processing in the CPU. Many laptops don't have a separate graphics card, leading to slow performance).

Comment: I was thinking along those lines, It looks like I will be doing some micro optimizations